# the :not operator in jquery

Tags: jquery

i want to select all elements without a special class.

i used:

```
 $('body:not(.noFocusOnKeypress)').live('keyup' ...
```

but it didnt work. and i have no idea why.

Comment: Wouldn't that select all body tags that don't have the class 'noFocusOnKeypress'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove `body` from your selector. As it stands, you are selecting all body elements that don't have that class, not all elements of any type that don't have that class. What you want is this:

```
$(':not(.noFocusOnKeypress)').live()
```

Note that this might be a fairly inefficient selector (I'm not familiar with the internals of the `:not` pseudo-class) and that it might improve performance to scope it a bit, like so:

```
$('#div-that-contains-these-elements :not(.noFocusOnKeypress)').live()
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
$(':not(.noFocusOnKeypress)').live
```